Access Data in MongoDbClient Cursor not working as expected
I have a single Document in my mongoDb collection:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "f8cc66adc6b5ce1fc99a2f59"
  },
  "isFlat": true,
  "schema": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "topLevelRecord",
    "fields": Array[]
  },
  "userId": "4d18fa67-c4ca-4d89-8e52-506774a8b12c",
  "filenames": [],
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-08-02T12:04:40.551Z"
  }
}

Now, I'd like to retrieve the field "schema".
Up till now I have done it with the toArray() function of the cursor like this:
await collection
    .aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: new ObjectId(`${fileId}`) }},
      { $project: { _id: 0, schema: 1}}
    ])
    .toArray()

This approach appears to be very time consuming. I assume because the Array in the schema field can be very nested.
In the official documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/) I learned about the other functions of the Cursor Object.
I tried the following:
cursor.stream().on("data", doc => console.log(doc));

which perfectly prints me the result I want in a very time-efficient manner but when I try to change it so that the result will be returned and attached to a variable, like so:
let schema = cursor.stream().on("data", doc => doc);
I get the whole Cursor Object attached to the schema variable.
Why is this the case? How to achieve the same result to be bounded to a variable than what is printed out on the console?

The .on() method defines a listener that is called asynchronously for each returned value.
The on method returns the cursor it was called on not the result of any invocation of the listener. See: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.8/classes/AbstractCursor.html#on
To demonstrate this timing, I executed the following using the mongosh shell:
console.log("before"); 
let schema=db.test.find()._cursor.stream().on("data",doc => console.log(doc)); 
console.log(schema.constructor)
console.log("after")

The output of the above was:
before
[class ReadableCursorStream extends Readable]
after
{ _id: ObjectId('66b1378276f1956167838726'), a: 1 }
{ _id: ObjectId('66b1378476f1956167838727'), a: 2 }
{ _id: ObjectId('66b1378576f1956167838728'), a: 3 }
{ _id: ObjectId('66b1378676f1956167838729'), a: 4 }
{ _id: ObjectId('66b1378876f195616783872a'), a: 5 }
{ _id: ObjectId('66b1378a76f195616783872b'), a: 6 }

This shows that the schema variable was assigned, and the last console.log call was executed, before the first document was received.

I kind of understand what you are trying to show regarding the timing but I'm not sure how I may use this information in order to reach my goal which is that I get only the 'data' assigned to my schema variable and not the whole cursor object.
I'd like to print the 'schema' variable the same content as the console.log(doc) commands.
How to do that in the same fast way?

The point is that the call to on returns long before the documents are sent back from the database, so there is no way for its return value to contain documents.  You would need to create a listener function that can accept documents 1 per call, and either process them directly or place them somewhere for later processing.
